# Массив содержит числа, вывести на экран все числа по 1 разу

Tags: c++, массивы, числа

Нужно вывести на экран все числа по 1 разу. Например массив: 1 2 5 2 1 9 8, должно быть:1 2 5 9 8

Я не понимаю как пропустить число если оно уже есть

Comment: Покажите код вывода всех чисел.

Comment: Выводить надо в том же порядке или неважно? 1 2 5 8 9 - годится?

Comment: for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    mas[i] = rand()%20;
    cout<<mas[i]<<endl;
}

Comment: Не важно в каком порядке, главное чтобы было

Comment: Вам необходимо почитать что такое структура set

Comment: Да не нужно использовать set в данном случае. Тут уже существует структура данных. Задачи создавать другую структуру не стоит же?! Просто создай массив булей на всем множестве и инициализируй его как false, и переводи в true соответствуеющие числа по индексам. Это, конечно, не самое оптимальное решение, но в данном случае пойдет. А использовать set -- это самое тупое, что можно сделать. Задача же не в том, чтобы научиться юзать контейнеры STL. Либо отсортировать его можно также. Все зависит от конкретной задачи: от диапазона значений, допустимого количесва расхода памяти, размера массива...

Comment: @megorit как раз использовать `set` не зная подробных условий задачи, это самое логичное :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(time(0));

    const int size_arr = 7;
    int arr[size_arr];

    //Заполнение массива случайными числами
    cout << "Исходны массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 20;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl; 

    //Проще всего сначала отсортировать массив
    sort(arr, arr + size_arr);


    cout << "Массив уникальных элементов: ";
    //Предыдущий элемент, который мы рассматривали
    int prevElem = arr[0];
    cout << prevElem << " ";
    for (int i = 1; i < size_arr; ++i) {
        //Если arr[i] не равен предыдущему элементы (например с 1 переходим на 2)
        //то выводим 2, и теперь предыдущий элемент = 2
        if (prevElem != arr[i]) {
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
            prevElem = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Так же если без сортировки, то можно сделать вот так:

```
int main() {
    const int size_arr = 7;
    int arr[] = { 1,2,5,2,1,9,8 };
    int unique_arr[size_arr] = { 0 };

    //Кол-во уникальных элементов
    int count = 0;
    //isValid = true если в unique_arr мы не найдем arr[i]
    //иначе false
    bool isValid = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; ++i) {
        isValid = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
            //Если мы нашли arr[i] в массиве unique_arr, 
            //то arr[i] не является уникальным элементов 
            if (arr[i] == unique_arr[j]) {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }

        //Если же мы не нашли arr[i] в массиве unique_arr, 
        //то добавляем его в этот массив
        if (isValid) {
            unique_arr[count] = arr[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

    //Выводим массив с уникальными элементами
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        cout << unique_arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Но этот алгоритм работает максимум за `O(n^2)`, так что если вам не важен порядок, то лучше воспользоваться первым способом.

Так же можете воспользоваться динамической структурой `set` и простой добавлять каждый элемент в экземпляр этой структуры.

```
const int size_arr = 7;
int arr[size_arr];
/* Заполнение массива случайными числами */

set<int> uniq_elems;

//Заполняем set элементами
for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
    uniq_elems.insert(arr[i]);

//Выводим уникальные (не повторяющиеся) элементы
for (set<int>::iterator i = uniq_elems.begin(); i != uniq_elems.end(); i++)
    cout << *i << " ";
```

Comment: Спасибо!  Как раз с сортировкой и нужно было)

Answer (score 3):

Если массив уже задан - проще удалить из него дубли, предварительно отсортировав - с помощью стандартных алгоритмов.

```
int a[] = {1,2,5,2,1,9,8};
sort(begin(a),end(a));
auto last = unique(begin(a),end(a));
for(int * i = a; i != last; ++i)
    cout << *i << " ";
```

Если это считывается из потока ввода - то можно воспользоваться множеством `set` - например, так:

```
set<int> z;
int a;

while(cin >> a)
    if (z.insert(a).second) cout << a << " ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Если эти числа не очень большие, и память не критична, можно использовать вариант быстрее. Например,  использовать их как индексы другого массива, с количеством элементов, большую, чем предельное значение этих чисел:

```
const unsigned int array_size = 12, //количество элементов
    max_val = 100;                  //максимальное значение всех чисел
unsigned arr[array_size] = {34, 21, 4, 23, 2, 4, 23, 0, 99,  0, 74, 34 }, //ваш массив
    pn[max_val + 1] = { 0 }; //под каждым индексом соответствующее значение
unsigned start = 1;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {            
    if (start && arr[i] == 0) //если  встретился первая ноль 
        start = 0; // будем использовать первый элемент индексного массива
    else
        pn[arr[i]] = arr[i];
}
//если в массиве был нулевой элемент, выводим
if (start == 0)
    cout << 0;
for (unsigned i = start; i <= max_val; ++i) {
    //пропускаем нули
    if (pn[i]) 
        cout << ' ' << pn[i];
}
```

Для чисел со знаком нужен индексный массив двойного размера, где в первой половине будут абсолютные значения отрицательных чисел, а во второй, двойное значение, и при выводе(использовании) выполнить обратные операции. Так что, не всегда стандартная сортировка самая оптимальная. Многое зависит от условий задачи...